# Postgresql indexes: enums and booleans first?

Tags: postgresql, index

When writing indexes, should I put the fields that represent enums first? That is, these fields have limited possible values: [0,1,2,3], for instance.

So, I might make an index

```
"my_index" btree (some_id_number, an_enum, boolean)
```

Would it be better to make it

```
"my_index" btree (an_enum, boolean, some_id_number)
```

?

I'm wondering is searching the 2nd option would take less time than the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contrary to wide-spread belief, it does not matter if you put columns with many different values first in the index or not.

What matters is that you put those columns first that are used with the `=` operator in the `WHERE` clause. If all columns are compared with `=` (and there are no `OR`s in the `WHERE` clause), the order does not matter for the performance of that query.

However, you want to put those columns first that appear in the `WHERE` conditions of most queries, so that the index can be used for other queries as well.

You should reconsider adding the `boolean` column to the index.  That *may* make sense, but if the condition is always `col = TRUE`, you may as well create the index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX ON tab (numeric_col, enum_col) WHERE bool_col;
```

Comment: By putting columns first that are used with the `=` operator, this effectively sets them up to be used by queries that have only 1 value for a column to be checked, as opposed to `where column IN(...)` queries, correct?

Comment: Yes. columns that are used with `IN` should be last.

Comment: @KdgDev  Efficiency for IN list is equivalent to that for =, at least in recent versions.  They can be in any order.  It is BETWEEN or inequality which ruins things for following columns, and so should likely be last.

Comment: @jjanes I didn't know that; I'll have to investigate.